# How to set breakpoint in Firebug on alert()?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

I have a very complex website and I know that somewhere is an `alert()` with a description. Is there a way to set a breakpoint on the `alert()` call? The HTML is generated, so I cannot just grep for the message.

Answer (score 28):

You can use the console to replace the `alert` function:

```
window.alert = function() { debugger; };
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebug's *Script* panel allows you to search for code throughout all your JavaScript sources.

[image: Firebug *Script* panel search for <code>alert(</code>]

So you can simply search for `alert(` or search for the message that the alert box shows and set a breakpoint on the line where it's called.

Another way is to use the [*Break On Next* button](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel#Break_On_Next) ( [image: *Break On Next* button in Firebug's *Script* panel] ) to stop at the next JavaScript statement that gets executed. So, click the button and then do the action that causes the alert box to be displaced.
*Note: This only works if there are no other event handlers called before the event showing the alert box.*

Comment: And if there are hundreds of such places, in obfuscated/minified code?

Comment: If the code is obfuscated and minified, you can at least unminify it via the *{}* button and search for the text within the `alert()`. Additionally you can try out @SLaks' trick. Though, if you don't have the sources for the minified code, it's normally third party code, for which you should file a bug report for its maintainer instead of trying to debug it yourself.

Comment: Or it may be legacy code. Or, god forbid, it may be `eval()`ed through string concatenation, or whatever. You missed the point. The point is hooking into library functions is a broadly useful debugging feature, it should be easy. Digging through arbitrary amounts of unfamiliar code isn't easy.

Comment: I agree that it should be easy to hook into library functions (while I believe debugging obfuscated or minified code should be avoided whenever possible). I've added a second solution using Firebug's *Break On Next* feature, though I don't know a simple solution that works for every use case. If you know a better way to find the `alert()` the questioner asking for, feel free to write an answer.